# How to convert perl to shell script?

Tags: shell, perl

I have a perl script which gets the filename as a input .. how can i convert it to shell script? Please help me

```
$path = shift;
$path =~ /.*\/(.*)/;
$filename = $1;

if (0 == length($filename)) {
    $filename = $path;
}   
$rev = `git log -- $path | head -n 3`;
$rev =~ /^Date:\s*(.*)\s*$/m;
$date = $1;

while (<STDIN>) {
    s/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date:   $date \$/;
    s/\$Revision[^\$]*\$/\$Revision: $ident \$/;
} continue {
    print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Why convert it?  What does this script need to do?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Is there's some part of the Perl program you don't understand? If so, ask about that. Is there something you don't know how to do using the unspecified shell you are using? If so, ask about that.

Comment: Usually I end up converting shell scripts to perl because the shell version is too slow. Going the other way feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sh` command/script will do the same thing as the provided Perl program:

```sh
perl -e'
    $path = shift;
    $path =~ /.*\/(.*)/;
    $filename = $1;

    if (0 == length($filename)) {
        $filename = $path;
    }   
    $rev = `git log -- $path | head -n 3`;
    $rev =~ /^Date:\s*(.*)\s*$/m;
    $date = $1;

    while (<STDIN>) {
        s/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date:   $date \$/;
        s/\$Revision[^\$]*\$/\$Revision: $ident \$/;
    } continue {
        print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
    }
' "$path"
```